# Why is there a gap next to my CSS grid layout on some browsers?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to use grids to display my pictures and make them cover the whole page while not changing aspect ratio. But when I open my page on Firefox or Chrome there's a huge gap on the right side.

**Disposition in VSC browser**
[image]

**Disposition in Firefox or Chrome**
[image]

I tried :

- setting `margin: 0;` in body
- setting `height, width, max-width` in html and body
- setting `width: 100%;` in container

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 350px 350px;
  gap: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.photo {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img class="photo" src="Japon_content/000001_minia.jpeg">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img class="photo" src="Japon_content/000002_minia.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should not trust the VSC Browser, it is not up to date with the W3C recommendations, or worse

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

No, the gap is correct...

```css
.container {
  display               : grid;
  grid-template-columns : 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows    : 350px 350px;
  gap                   : 2em;
  padding               : 1em;
  }
.container div {             /* added to show real */
  background-color : yellow; /* grid element size  */
  }
.photo {
  max-width  : 100%;
  object-fit : cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img class="photo" src="https://picsum.photos/350/350?random=1">
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="photo" src="https://picsum.photos/350/350?random=2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by applying these styles to the `photo` class:

```
.photo {
    width: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```